# How much data will Super Mario Run use?

Tags: super-mario-run

How much cellular data does Super Mario Run use? Does anyone have a rating of MB/H?
I need to know because I am mostly on cellular, and not wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've marked this as a community wiki post, because I think this will take multiple data points.

I've played on a mix of cellular and wifi since launch day.  On cellular I've mostly played Toad Rally, which would naturally use much more network bandwidth.  I've also done some shopping and read the notices/alerts several times.  I've probably played about 3-4 hours on cellular (this is a total guess) and I've used 26mb of data, which includes initially setting it up and a partial DLC download before switching to wifi.